# How to make a Java program take input from an iOS app

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

So I'm writing software that will basically take input from a button press on an iOS or Android app. Despite the many combinations of keywords I've tried on Google, I cannot find any information on how I would do this.

For my prototype, I just want to press a basic button on a mobile app and have it run a function in my program. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your Java program running?  Is it hosted as some sort of web service?

Comment: @paulw11 I plan for it to run on the end user's machine.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 You should setup TCP connections make a server on one device and a client on the other one I've done exactly the same thing with android and windows.This is for the local connection for internet you should have a server and go with PHP,PUSH NOTIFICATION

Comment: You will need to make some sort of network connection; Your java program could listen on a network socket; It could use Bonjour/MDNS to advertise itself. Your mobile application would then locate the service and open a network connection

Comment: @stevemoretz and paulw11 This is some great information. Thank you! Would either of you be able to provide me a link to a tutorial that you believe covers the subject well? I feel like this will be extremely helpful information when it comes to learning about software development. EDIT: Also, is there another method that can be used as well? Like Bluetooth connection or something that doesn't REQUIRE internet. Needing internet is not a problem, I would just like to know if there is more than one way to accomplish this.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 for TCP you don't need internet you need to be connected to the same wifi it can be a mobile hotspot with its mobile data off which means no internet connection is needed.That's why I said Local And Online TCP works locally for you.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 Yes you also can use bluetooth I haven't tried it personally.But of cource you can use bluetooth and NFC as well.There are plenty of code on the web just go one by one first learn android then IOS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local:
Check out this example it has both code for IOS and Android:

> [IOS to Android and vice versa TCP server client connection using sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994591/ios-to-android-and-vice-versa-tcp-server-client-connection-using-sockets)

Online:for php and push notifications.You need to have a server I suggest wamp for start you can install it on your pc it's a virtual server:

> http://www.wampserver.com/en/

and for the push notification service with php you can use:

> https://pusher.com

Comment: Thank you very much to both you and paulw. I will be sure to read up on these and figure out which one works best for my software. I appreciate the help so late at night.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 My Pleasure good luck and post your codes here at the end if you liked so other people can use it too.

Comment: Once I read up and implement it well enough to share, I will be sure to edit my post with the code.